# How to mannually add a array of JLabel to JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jlabel

I've been trying to make an array of labels displayed on JFrame. But JFrame couldn't display the created labels. It just appears blank. How to fix this problem?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "This is a sample sentence.";
    String[] words = s.split("\\s+");

    JLabel[] jLblWords=new JLabel[words.length];

    /* create labels */

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        jLblWords[i]=new JLabel(words[i]);

      }

 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: cause you didn't add any Panel to your Jframe !

Comment: Where are you adding labels? You just created the array but neither label is added

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @StanislavL how to add jlabel array to jframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- JFrame has BorderLayout implemented in API, in BorderLayout only one JComponents can be placed to one of 5th areas
- your code posted here isn't completed, doesn't shows how is arrays of JLabels added to JFrame
- to start with GridLayout

---

- I'd be suggest to use JTable (in JScrollPane) instead of bunch of JLabels added to JFrame

Comment: I didn't add JLabels to JFrame. I don't know how to do that. I'm newbee to swings api.